# Zabbix trigger dependency

Tags: triggers, notifications, dependencies, zabbix

Let's say I have two hosts. One is a firewall and the other one a L2 device.
I set ping check items with different time interval. 1-minute interval for firewall, and 5-minute interval for L2.
And I also set triggers for both of them just to be informed when there is a disconnection or error. And the FW trigger is dependent on L2 trigger.
If there is a problem in FW, I should get a notification of that trigger, and if there is a problem in L2, I should get one notification from L2 trigger only.
However, I am just curious how this works even though their ping check time intervals are not the same.
Regardless the time interval difference, does Zabbix check L2's ping right after it detects any problem in FW so that it determines whether the problem is from L2 or not?

Answer (score 1):

The notification depends on the action steps, it can be sent immediately at problem creation or after N minutes.

The problem creation depends on the triggers creation and dependancy.

The trigger depends on both the interval checks and the trigger condition.

For instance, you can set itemX at 1m and itemY at 5min for ping loss. If you create a trigger that checks only the `.last()` value then disconnect the cables from X and Y: ideally you'll see a trigger after one minute and the second one after 4 more minutes (and the dependancy will kick in).

It will work even with an average check of the last N minutes etc.

However, I advise not to do anything similar in production unless you want an headache

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. So, if I use `last()` then it will wait for another 4 minutes to check if it depends on another one? What do I need to do if I want to immediately check the other dependent item when I see a trigger? I want to check my itemY right after I see a trigger of itemX even though it did not get to 5 minutes.

Comment: You can check any item by hand whenever you want, from Configuration - Host - Item - Check now. But it's better to have homogenous intervals for a number of reasons, just think of a graph comparison or a report or a post-mortem.

Comment: Okay. The reason I want to differentiate the intervals is to reduce the cpu resources. I have 7000 firewall devices being monitored and I do not want to frequently check ping for another 7000 L2 devices connected to the firewalls. I need to detect the real origin of a problem without using too much cpu resource.

Comment: Yes I got it, but it's almost 99% wrong nonetheless, because when you'll need data you'll have two different granularities, difficult to compare (and to trigger, too!).